# odoo program add mail follower no default subtype

Tags: odoo

```py
class jj_loan(models.Model):
    _name       = 'jj_loan.jj_loan'
    name        = fields.Char(required=True)
    _inherit    = ['mail.thread', 'ir.needaction_mixin'] 
    state       = fields.Selection([('Draft','Draft'),('Apply','Apply')] ,default="Draft") 
    manager_id  = fields.Many2one('hr.employee', 'Approval',default=_supervisor_get)

   def add_approve_follower(self):
        vals={}
        partner_id = []
        ptn = self.env['res.partner'].search([('email', '=', self.manager_id.user_id.email)]) //get partner id by email
        if not ptn:return vals  //if get fail return {}
        for x in self.message_follower_ids:
            if x.partner_id.id == ptn.id:return vals //if already added in followers return  {}
        partner_id.append(ptn.id)
        vals['message_follower_ids'] = [(0,0,{
                'res_model':'jj_loan.jj_loan',
                'partner_id':pid}) for pid in partner_id]
        return  vals;  //return message_follower_ids

    @api.one
    def jj_loan_aprrove(self): 
        vals = self.add_account_follower(); //get now followers 
        vals['state'] = 'Approve' 
        self.write(vals)
        self.send_followers( _("Approved") )
        return True

    @api.multi
    def send_followers(self,body):
        followers = [x.partner_id.id for x in self.message_follower_ids]
        self.message_post(body=body,type="notification",subtype="mt_comment",parnter_ids=followers)
        return True
```

when   jj_loan_aprrove button clicked , manager_id is automatically added into the follower list, but ,when message created ,the manager can not get notification. and then I found this caused as bellowes:

[image: manager is following this thread, but after I clicked the edit icon. and I see the two checkbox are unchecked ,the first checkbox should be checked by default]
[image: the two checkbox are unchecked] 
[image: this is the normal status when I add followers manually]

I want to know how to add followers programmely and make the default checkbox checked
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, after read the odoo default addons mail, I found message_follower_ids should have key for res_model so the solution for this question is :

```
default_subtypes = self.env['mail.message.subtype'].search([  ('default', '=', True),      '|', ('res_model', '=', model_id), ('res_model', '=', False)])
vals['message_follower_ids'] = [(0,0,{
          'res_model':model_id,
          'subtype_ids': [(6, 0, default_subtypes.ids)],
          'partner_id':pid}) for pid in partner_id]
return vals;
```